# Make an accordion with angularjs/ui-bootstrap an using the ng-model

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, accordion, angular-ui-bootstrap

I use angularJs and bootstrap. I have made an accordion where I have put a select for choose the value of the filter and the data-ng-model which doesn't work (the select works if he is not in an accordion). Here is my code:

```
<accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
    <accordion-group is-open="isOpen">
        <accordion-heading>
            Country<i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': isOpen, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !isOpen}"></i>
        </accordion-heading>
        <select data-ng-model="country" class="input-medium inputFilter form-control">
            <option value="">All country</option>
            <option value="1">Switzerland</option>
            <option value="2">France</option>
            <option value="3">Spain</option>
        </select>
    </accordion-group>
</accordion>
<div data-ng-repeat="city in listcity |filter:country">
    {{city.name}}, {{city.country}}
</div>
```

I have look at UI-Bootstrap for the accordion. I thinks I had to do a directive for make it work but the directive doesn't work with the accordion. here is my directive which doesn't work

```
app.directive('accordion', function () {
return {
    scope: {
        dataNgModel: '=',
    },
  };
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you wanted. But i use ng-change to setup the new filter value.

Controller:

```
function AccordionDemoCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.oneAtATime = true;
  //default: all countrys
  $scope.country = '';
  //example data
  $scope.listcity = [{
    name: 'Madrid',
    country: '3'
  }, {
    name: 'Paris',
    country: '2'
  }, {
    name: 'Lyon',
    country: '2'
  }, {
    name: 'Zurich',
    country: '1'
  }];

  //set a new selection
  $scope.setCountry = function(cid) {
    $scope.country = cid;
  }
}
```

Markup:

```
 <select ng-model="country" ng-change="setCountry(country)" class="input-medium inputFilter form-control">
```

See it working [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/bvc3tqS1lDs9CYRQMf1e?p=preview)

Btw: The example directive is the shortest I have ever seen. Ahh, I whish it was that easy:-)

Comment: Thanks it's exactly what i was looking for. It was the first time I was trying to do a directive :), I stil have a lot of work to do haha

Comment: Hello guys, am stuck with an angularjs-accordion problem can you help ? ... Its [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23003721/angularjs-divide-list-respective-to-their-headers-in-an-accordion)