# angular-bootstrap accordion databinding issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

I have 2 drop downs with same models, one inside accordion and another outside.
The outside drop down works fine in terms of 2-way databinding but the one inside the accordion seems to have only 1-way binding, in other words selecting in the UI is not setting the model value. I found a suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22760785/make-an-accordion-with-angularjs-ui-bootstrap-an-using-the-ng-model/22762336#22762336) that using `ng-change` will fix this problem. It fixed for `<textarea>` but not for `<select>`.
Wondering this could be bug in [angular-ui](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker). Can someone help on this issue. Thanks in advance!

**outside accordion**

```
 <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="category">Category</label>
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <select id="category" ng-model="category" name="category" type="text" class="form-control">
                    <option ng-repeat="category in config.categories.sort()"  value="{{category}}">
                    {{category}}</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
```

**Inside accordion**

```
<accordion close-others="false">
    <accordion-group>
 <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="category">Category</label>
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <select id="category" ng-model="category" ng-change="setCategory(category)"  name="category" type="text" class="form-control">
                    <option ng-repeat="category in config.categories.sort()"  value="{{category}}">
                    {{category}}</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div> 
  </accordion-group>
  </accordion>
```

my model `categories` is an array of string:

example:

```
"categories": [
            "Admin API",
            "Admin License",
            "adminGUI",
            "antennahouse",
            "App Builder",
            "Backup/Restore",
            "Basis"]
```

**ng-change function**

```
 $scope.setCategory = function(category) {
     $scope.category = category;
 };
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Binding to an attribute of the scope directly is almost a bad idea, because many directives define their own scope, and if your widget (the select box) is inside such a directive, you will in fact bind to an attribute of the child scope rather than binding to an attribute of the controller scope.

The rule of thumbs is thus: always have a dot in your ng-model. The form controls should modify an object of your scope, and not your scope directly.

In your controller:

```
$scope.selection = {};
```

In your view:

```
<select ng-model="selection.category" ...>
```

Also, note that you're using the same ID to identify two select boxes. That will make your DOM invalid. An ID identifies an element uniquely.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @JB. I used those 2 doms for illustration pupose only. I use only the one inside accordion. For the sake of the explaining the problem I showed 2 examples. Perhaps in retrospect I should have been clear about that. And yes you are right. I was setting `$scope.category= null` instead of `{}`. Thanks again!

Comment: @JB Nizet can you please help me to solve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50073157/data-api-response-not-binding-in-accordion-in-angular4