# AngularJS ng-submit Not working inside accordion tags

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-bootstrap

Following form works correctly with validations when its not inside the accordion tags, but when its inside the accordion tags even the methods won't fire.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <form name="myForm" role="form" ng-submit='myAccount()' novalidate="novalidate">
    <input type="text" name="myName" ng-model='myName' required>
    <div ng-show="myForm.myName.$dirty && myForm.myName.$invalid || submitted">
        <small class="error" ng-show="myForm.myName.$error.required">
             Your Name is required
        </small>
    </div>
    <div>
       <button type="submit" ng-click="submitted = true">Add</button>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope','$location', '$log', function($scope,$location,$log)
{   
    $scope.myAccount = function()
    {
        if($scope.myForm.$valid)
        {
            $log.log('Valid Form');
        }
        else
        {
            $log.log('Validation Failed');
        }
    }
}]);
```

I want to use the above form inside the following accordion tags since it should be visible inside accordion. But the issue is when I place it inside the accordion tags the ng-submit won't work and it doesn't even gives any errors. Is there a solutions to this? is it a bug in accordion tags?

```
<accordion close-others="true">
    <accordion-group>
         <accordion-heading>
                <!-- form html content goes here -->                
         </accordion-group>          
</accordion>
```

Comment: you're probably not having this issue anymore [but here is an explanation that you might find helpful.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24593154/3199310

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.pho.myAccount = function()
{
    if($scope.myForm.$valid)
    {
        $log.log('Valid Form');
    }
    else
    {
        $log.log('Validation Failed');
    }
}

<form name="myForm" role="form" ng-submit='pho.myAccount()' nov ..
```

check with these two modifications :) not sure

Comment: what is pho? @Kalhano

Comment: is it working or not ? may be `accordion` directive will create a separate scope so look at about phototypical inheritance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs

Comment: the form doesn't even load when i do that. please explain what it does @Kalhano

Comment: cannot see a solution to mine